# Como customizar as tags og(Open Graph) na pagina do post - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou criando um template do zero para Wordpress, mas gostaria de alterar o conteúdo das tags og de acordo com o conteudo do post, ou seja definir imagem titulo e descrição

Agradeço desde já

Comment: Já pensou em utilizar o plugin [Wordpress SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recomendação no [Guideline para Desenvolvimento de Themes](http://make.wordpress.org/themes/guidelines/) é para separar funcionalidade do desenho. Coisas como SEO e Shortcodes não pertencem em themes, pois ao trocar de theme -que acontece com frequencia- o site perde essas funcionalidades, precisando ser migradas de um theme a outro. Mesmo que você esteja desenvolvendo seu próprio theme, muito provavelmente vai desenvolver outro em algum momento do futuro.

O que é mais indicado no desenvolvimento do theme é seguir o [Guia de SEO para Themes](https://yoast.com/wordpress-seo-theme/) <sup>[*(mirror)*](http://web.archive.org/web/20140122071238/http://yoast.com/wordpress-seo-theme/)</sup> do Yoast. E mesmo sendo um *theme developer* nada impede [criar plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) que trabalhem com seus themes.

Isso dito, o que o plugin [WordPress SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) faz é imprimir as tags na `<head>` usando o *action hook* `wp_head`.

Aqui, comecei a enxugar a classe completa onde o plugin cuida dessa saída. É necessário [**conferir os outros métodos dentro da classe**](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wordpress-seo/tags/1.6/frontend/class-opengraph.php) para completar as meta tags. O código está comentado e cada tag que falta tem o nome do método onde se pode conferir como Yoast lida com cada meta `property`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SOPT) OG Meta Tags
 */

add_action( 'wp_head', 'sopt_32080_head', 1 ); // Prioridade 1, imprime o antes possível

function sopt_32080_head()
{
    # POST ATUAL
    # as Conditional Tags como is_front_page, is_archive, is_singular, etc, cuidarão de saber qual a página atual
    # http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags
    global $post;

    # LINGUAGEM
    echo '<meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR" />' . "\n";

    # TIPO
    if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) {
        $type = 'website';
    } elseif ( is_singular() ) {
        $type = 'article';
    }  else {
        // We use "object" for archives etc. as article doesn't apply there
        $type = 'object';
    }
    echo '<meta property="og:type" content="' . $type . '" />' . "\n";

    # TITULO
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        $title = 'Article - ' . $post->post_title;
    } else if ( is_front_page() ) {
        $title = 'Website - ' . get_bloginfo('name');
    } else {
        $title = 'Outro tipo de página';
    }
    echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . $title . '" />' . "\n";

    # TODO: OUTRAS TAGS

    # fb:app_id ou fb:admins
    // public function site_owner()

    # og:description
    // public function description()

    # og:url
    // public function url()

    # og:site_name
    // public function site_name()

    # article:publisher
    // public function website_facebook()

    # ARTIGOS INDIVIDUAIS
    if ( is_singular() && ! is_front_page() ) {
        # article:author
        // public function article_author_facebook()

        # article:tag
        // public function tags()

        # article:section
        // public function category()

        # article:published_time e article:modified_time e og:updated_time
        // public function publish_date()
    }

    # og:image
    // public function image()
}
```

Comment: Valeu! cara era isso que precisava. XD